# Sorting Unicode strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How do I sort Unicode (foreign) strings in my iPhone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping me.

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`

this API will do the sorting with respect to localization. Otherwise strings of different languages will be treated as a unicode strings and comparison fails.

Here is the solution:

```
NSComparisonResult sortLocationsForStr(NSString* str1, NSString* str2, void *context)
{
    return [str1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:str2];
}

[myArrayToSort sortUsingFunction:sortLocationsForStr context:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

All strings in Objective-C (NSString*) are unicode strings. They are sequences of unicode characters (as opposed to sequences of encoded bytes). You can sort an array of strings using the methods provided by NSArray.

```
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"はじめまして", @"русский язык", @"คนอ้วน ๆ", nil];

NSArray* mySortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This will sort the strings by their unicode order, if you have some other sorting condition then provide a custom sorting selector or elaborate on your question.

Comment: What do you mean "in their Unicode order"?  You mean in the order defined by the Unicode Collation Algorithm?  That would be the Unicode order.  If you mean code point order, that’s pure garbage and does not produce an alphabetic sort.

Comment: @tchrist: +1. I agree sorting on point order is not meaningful. However the question did not mention 'alphabetical ordering' at all. For all I know they wanted an arbitrary sorted array for binary search? I encouraged them to elaborate their question, and I would have elaborated my answer. Maybe you could create an answer explaining how to use the Unicode Collation Algorithm in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort using sort descriptors, you can also sort like so:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor descriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES];
NSArray* mySortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
```

"description" works OK as a key for NSString values, since description is documented to return itself.

The advantage of going the NSSortDescriptor route is that you can have more than one sort descriptor, or you can select to use a descending sort instead.

Comment: If you want to sort an array of NSStrings with a sort descriptor, it's probably better to use `self` as the key.  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGEBBJ

Comment: for NSString, "description" is equivalent in that it always returns the NSString object itself.  I think it's less confusing than "self" which could be misinterpreted as being the class doing the calling and not the objects in the array...