# Comparing Unicode Strings in C Returns Different Values Than C#

Tags: c#, c, unicode, utf-8, string-comparison

So I am attempting to write a compare function in C which can take a UTF-8 encoded Unicode string and use the [Windows CompareStringEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and I am expecting it to work just like .NET's [CultureInfo.CompareInfo.Compare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sk4bdtt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Now the function I have written in C works some of the time, but not in all cases and I'm trying to figure out why. Here is a case that fails (passes in C#, not in C):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CompareOptions compareOptions = CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth;

string stringA = "คนอ้วน ๆ";
string stringB = "はじめまして";
//Result is -1 which is expected
int result = cultureInfo.CompareInfo.Compare(stringA, stringB);
```

And here is what I have written in C. Keep in mind this is supposed to take a UTF-8 encoded string and use the Windows CompareStringEx() function so conversion is necessary.

```
// Compare flags for the string comparison
#define COMPARE_STRING_FLAGS (NORM_IGNORECASE | NORM_IGNOREKANATYPE | NORM_IGNOREWIDTH)

int CompareStrings(int lenA, const void *strA, int lenB, const void *strB) 
{
    LCID ENGLISH_LCID = MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), SORT_DEFAULT);
    int compareString = -1;

    // Get the size of the strings as UTF-18 encoded Unicode strings. 
    // Note: Passing 0 as the last parameter forces the MultiByteToWideChar function
    // to give us the required buffer size to convert the given string to utf-16s
    int strAWStrBufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCSTR)strA, lenA, NULL, 0);
    int strBWStrBufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCSTR)strB, lenB, NULL, 0);

    // Malloc the strings to store the converted UTF-16 values
    LPWSTR utf16StrA = (LPWSTR) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, strAWStrBufferSize * sizeof(WCHAR));
    LPWSTR utf16StrB = (LPWSTR) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, strBWStrBufferSize * sizeof(WCHAR));

    // Convert the UTF-8 strings (SQLite will pass them as UTF-8 to us) to standard  
    // windows WCHAR (UTF-16\UCS-2) encoding for Unicode so they can be used in the 
    // Windows CompareStringEx() function.
    if(strAWStrBufferSize != 0)
    {
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCSTR)strA, lenA, utf16StrA, strAWStrBufferSize);
    }
    if(strBWStrBufferSize != 0)
    {
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCSTR)strB, lenB, utf16StrB, strBWStrBufferSize);
    }

    // Compare the strings using the windows compare function.
    // Note: We subtract 1 from the size since we don't want to include the null termination character
    if(NULL != utf16StrA && NULL != utf16StrB)
    {
        compareValue = CompareStringEx(L"en-US", COMPARE_STRING_FLAGS, utf16StrA, strAWStrBufferSize - 1, utf16StrB, strBWStrBufferSize - 1, NULL, NULL, 0);
    }

    // In the Windows CompareStringEx() function, 0 indicates an error, 1 indicates less than, 
    // 2 indicates equal to, 3 indicates greater than so subtract 2 to maintain C convention
    if(compareValue > 0)
    {
        compareValue -= 2;
    }

    return compareValue;
}
```

Now if I run the following code, I expect the result to be -1 based on the .NET implementation (see above) but I get 1 indicating that the strings are greater than:

```
char strA[50] = "คนอ้วน ๆ";
char strB[50] = "はじめまして";

// Will be 1 when we expect it to be -1
int result = CompareStrings(strlen(strA), strA, strlen(strB), strB);
```

Any ideas on why the results I'm getting are different? I'm using the same LCID/cultureInfo and compareOptions in both implementations and the conversions are successful as far as I can tell.

FYI: This function will be used as a custom collation in SQLite. Not relevant to the question but in case anyone is wondering why the function signature is the way it is.

**UPDATE:** I also determined that when running the same code in .NET 4 I would see the behavior I saw in the native code. As a result there was now a discrepancy between .NET versions. See my answer below for the reasons behind this.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but you are leaking memory.

Comment: Is it possible that the `CompareStrings` is treating the bytes as characters in some 8-bit codepage and applying collation rules rather than comparing the byte values? I would expect such broken behavior from Windows...

Comment: @dalle: How am I leaking memory? Any enhancements to this code are appreciated.

Comment: To free the memory returned from `GlobalAlloc`, use the `GlobalFree` function. But you you may think about using another allocation function than `GlobalAlloc` which is a bit slower than the alternatives. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366533%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: In addition, according to google translate, "คนอ้วน ๆ" means "Fat people" in Thai hahahaha

Comment: @dalle: Ah ok, yeah I just forgot to include that in the post, had it on my machine haha. Thanks and I'll look into alternatives.

Comment: @Daniel: Wow I didn't even know that! I just Googled some Unicode characters and thats what cameup

Comment: @tkeE2036: Funny. I thought that you were getting a rise out of having lots of people type "Fat People" without knowing what it meant.

Comment: As I speak Thai (well, a bit anyway), first thing I noticed were the combination of CultureInfo("en-US") and "fat people"

Comment: Well this was where I found the strings initially, here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385073/sorting-unicode-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out the issue after contacting Microsoft support. Here is what they had to say about the issue:

> The reason for the issue you are seeing, namely,  running CompareInfo.Compare against the same string with the same compare options but getting different return values when run under different versions of the .NET Framework, is that the sorting rules are tied to the Unicode spec, which evolves over time.  Historically .NET has snapped data for side by side releases to correspond to the newest version of Windows and the corresponding version of Unicode implemented at that time so 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 correspond to the version for Windows XP or Server 2003, whereas v4.0 matched the Vista sorting rules.  As a result the sorting rules for the various versions of the .NET Framework have changed over time.

This also means that when I ran the native code I was calling the sort methods that adhered ot the Vista sorting rules and when I ran in .NET 3.5 I was running sort methods that used the Windows XP sorting rules. Seems odd to me that the Unicode spec would change in such a manner as to cause such a dramatic difference but apparently that's the case here. Seems to me that changing the Unicode spec in such a dramatic way is a fantastic way to break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your code performs several steps here - it's not clear whether it's the compare step which is failing or not.

As a first step, I would write out - in both the .NET code and the C code - the exact UTF-16 code units which you've got in `utf16StrA`, `utf16StrB`, `stringA` and `stringB`. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that there's a problem in the input data you're using in the C code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to explicitly declare UTF-8 strings in C. I believe you can do wchar_t (which are UCS-2 or UTF-16 right?) by prefixing your string with an L.

Comment: @tkeE2036: I don't know, to be honest. I wouldn't expect it to be part of the type you use, but a compiler switch to determine which encoding you're using.

Comment: No, strings in C can't be declared to be UTF-8. C strings are just null terminated byte sequences. The encoding of those sequences is up to the program or library to enforce. Typically string literals contain the literal bytes from the source code, so the string will use the source code encoding. C++11 does have a 'u8' prefix that will tell the compiler to convert a literal from the source code encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: @bames53: Byte sequences, or character sequences? What if `char` isn't a single byte? I thought that was feasible, but I may be wrong...

Comment: In C `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition and `char` has the size of the smallest addressable unit. It's possible that this isn't a byte (or maybe more accurately that the platform's bytes aren't 8 bits) but you probably don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @bames53: Right. So presumably one *can* create UTF-8-encoded strings in C and declare them as `char *` by providing the *bytes* instead of the characters. But the chances of getting it right without care are slim :)

Comment: Yeah. What I meant is that there's no way to declare to the C compiler that the string should be UTF-8, causing the compiler to take care of it for you when UTF-8 is not the normal char* encoding. You can however stick whatever data you want in those byte sequences, including UTF-8 data (e.g., using \x escapes or by encoding the source code in UTF-8).

Comment: In fact my preferred method for writing Unicode aware programs is to treat char* internally as always UTF-8 and convert it at boundaries as required. This is because Linux and OS X generally use UTF-8 as well so there are no boundaries, whereas using wchar_t to accomodate Windows has complications not only on *nix, but also on Windows! Being able to write `std::cout << "はじめまして" << std::endl;` and have it work with no other effort is very nice. `std::wcout << L"はじめまして" << std::endl;` doesn't work nearly so well even on Windows.

Comment: @bames53: So does my answer need any changes, or is it correct?

Comment: A problem with the input seemed likely to me too, but from the comments in the other answer now I'd guess that the input data is correct (tkeE2036 saved the source code as UTF-8). Still, it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Actually you are probably right that the input data is wrong. I'd forgotten that cl.exe does not just take the source code bytes literally. Instead it will translate from what it guesses the source code encoding to be to the system's code page. So if the source code is saved as UTF-8 with BOM then the literals are translated into the system's code page. On the other hand, when I save the code as UTF-8 without BOM (so that cl.exe will get confused and not do any translation) the result of the comparison is still 1 for me.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was under the impression that this was an issue with the native and managed code however further investigation revealed this discrepancy exists also between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4 if you run the same exact code. I contacted Microsoft support thinking it was a bug in their code. See my answer for their comments. (though I am a bit skeptical that the Unicode spec changed so dramatically)

Answer (score 2):

What you are *hoping* for here is that your text editor will save the source code file in utf-8 format.  And that the compiler will then somehow *not* interpret the source code as utf-8.  That's too much to hope for, at least on my compiler:

```
warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u0E04' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
```

Fix:

```
const wchar_t* strA = L"คนอ้วน ๆ";
const wchar_t* strB = L"はじめまして";
```

And remove the conversion code.

Comment: When I saved the file with the new Unicode characters Visual Studio asked what code page I wanted associated with the document so I might be good there. I also need strA and strB represented as UTF-8 and then converted to wchar_t since this is the way SQLite will function.

Comment: @tkeE2036: Which code page did you choose? Visual Studio has issues with UTF-8 encoded source files.

Comment: @dalle: It was the UTF-8 code page. Is that not what I wanted?

Comment: Definitely check the literal values. I think if you're using UTF-8 with BOM then cl.exe will convert them to the system codepage.